# How to replace coma separated values with list of Images?

Tags: flutter

I have this layout:

[image]

Code:

```
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                    return Column(
                     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child:Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Padding(
                                      padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 6.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Image.asset("assets/images/"+ _displayedList[position].brand+".jpg", height: 40, width: 40),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 6.0, 12.0, 12.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            _displayedList[position].location,
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 6.0, 12.0, 12.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            _displayedList[position].distance.toString()+" KM",
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0), textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ), flex: 3,
                            ),

                            Expanded(
                              child:Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Padding(
                                      padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 6.0, 12.0, 12.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            "\$"+ _displayedList[position].price.toString(),
                                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey), textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 6.0, 12.0, 12.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            _displayedList[position].facilities.toString(),
                                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey), textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ), flex: 2,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Divider(
                          height: 2.0,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: _displayedList.length
              );
```

See the **Restaurant, Toilet** text, for example?
In the code above, take a look at "_displayedList[position].facilities.toString()"

Insead of using Text, how to programmatically display them using images, e.g:
[image]

Or if _displayedList[position].facilities.toString() is "ATM", then only ATM icon is displayed.

**UPDATE**
I tried Zvi Karp's suggestion bellow, like this (use Image instead of Icon):

```
 Map<String, Image> _serviceImages = {
    'atm': Image.asset("assets/images/atm.png", height: 30, width: 30),
    'toilet': Image.asset("assets/images/toilet.png", height: 30, width: 30),
    'restaurant': Image.asset("assets/images/restaurant.png", height: 30, width: 30)
  };


Padding(
    padding:
        const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 6.0, 12.0, 12.0),
        child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: _serviceImages[_displayedList[position].facilities.toString().split(",").map<Image>((icon) => Image(_categories[icon])).toList()]
        ),
    ),
```

Flutter complains:

> The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type
>   'List'

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to create a icon map, for example:

```
Map<String, IconData> _categories = {
    'Sports' : Icons.directions_run,
    'Politics' : Icons.gavel,
    'Science' : Icons.wb_sunny,
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: _categories[_displayedList[position].facilities.toString().split(",").map<Icon>((icon) => Icon(_categories[icon])).toList()
)
```